# Python code error

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool

```
import arcpy
inputlayer=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
output=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
arcpy.Select_analysis( inputlayer, output,"LAYER = 'Unknown Line Type'")
```

I am new to Python migrating from VB.Net. I want to select all items of a feature where the field LAYER = Unknown Line Type.

But I am always having problem in executing this code.
This image remains for more than an hour and nothing happens.
I Have only 80 features with no index.

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting when you run the code that you have presented?

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to specify the number of features that are involved, and whether you have constructed an index on the column. Even when I select from millions of rows, my query time rarely drifts into minutes, but I always build indexes on my query column(s).

Comment: Are you presenting every line of code in Script1?

Comment: What gets printed with  `print inputlayer` and `print output`